# How to store authorizations codes in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, oauth, oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

I am doing the setup of OAuth with Firebase for a Google Actions app.
I chose the Authorization Code Flow and I am following the steps from the doc here :
https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow

Step 4 of Handle user sign-in, there are two ways to create an authorization code. 
I prefer the one that use a json to store the expiration date to save a database call in the next step.

Now, I would like to store all the authorization codes generated and I am not sure about what is the best way to do so. My auth codes are very long (170 characters), and I am not sure if it is a great way to store them as Index in Firebase. 
Here is what my DB looks like : 
[image: My Firebase Database]
I thought about using a hash to shorten them, but I am afraid about hash not being unique.

What would be the cleanest way to store auth codes in Firebase ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Keys can be up to 768 characters, so using the auth code as a key makes perfect sense.

Using a hash is reasonable since a good hash has a very low chance of collision, but doesn't provide you much additional value in your case and will (slightly) increase computation time and program complexity.